# GeoGraphics - mapping the Moon

Tags: curated-data, geography, astronomy, projection

The link [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/entity-based-geocomputation/map-lunar-maria.html) shows a nice way to depict the map of the Moon in *Mathematica*. But, is there a way to center the Mollweide projection onto the far side of the Moon?

Comment: I think you are looking for [the `GeoCenter` option](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoCenter.html) to `GeoGraphics`.

Comment: @MarcoB Many thanks! Can you post it as an answer, so that I can tick it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`GeoCenter` option](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoCenter.html) to `GeoGraphics`.

```
GeoGraphics[
  GeoCenter -> {0., 180.},
  GeoModel -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"],
  GeoProjection -> "Mollweide",
  GeoRange -> All, Background -> Black
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: For a Mollweide moon map centered on the far side: `GeoGraphics[GeoCenter -> {0., 180.}, GeoModel -> Entity["PlanetaryMoon", "Moon"], GeoProjection -> "Mollweide", GeoRange -> All, Background -> Black]`

Comment: @J.M. Thank you! I've swapped your example in, since it's more relevant to the question.